# Expected value - Prisoner's problem

Tags: probability

Suppose there are two prisoners whose jail time depends on the strategies that they use during the interrogation.
And suppose the Jail time can be $0, 1, 2,$ or $3$ years.

For prisoner $1$,
I found the probability for each prison time as, $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3$

May I know the meaning of the expected time of the prisoner $1$ in jail and the method to find it.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ E[x] $ is the expected value of (random) variable $ x $.
An informal definition states that it's the middle (according to probabilities) value that occures.
The formula is $ E[x] = \sum_{x = X} p_{x = X}X $, where X are the possible values of the random variable $ x $.
So, $ E[x] = 0 * p_0 + 1 * p_1 + 2 * p_2 + 3 * p_3 $.

Comment: Thank you very much